# Adding users from text file

Tags: bash, scripts, users, groups

I'm trying to add multiple users from a text file and then to a group but I keep getting this error:

```
'seradd: invalid user name 'srogers
```

My current script is:

```
for i in $(cat users.txt)
do
  echo $i
  sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash -G interns $i
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `newusers` ? Whats the content of `users.txt` ?

Comment: I tried that just now but when I checked my list of users the users were not there. In 'users.txt' there are a list of usernames only such as 'bdrake'.

Comment: I don't understand..perhaps you should add at least a portion of the file `users.txt`

Comment: See how the closing quote is overwriting the first character of the error message? That means you have a carriage return (\r) in your file: do `dos2unix users.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not give us insights about you particular task and about contents of `users.txt` file, but I could give a few recommendations that will eliminate simple problems.

**First**

Always surround all variables with double quotes `"` in bash scripts. This simple trick help to avoid a lot script problems. In your particular case replace all `$i` with `"$i"`.

**Second**

Always add double dash `--` at the end of command line to signify the end of command options. It helps to avoid problems when positional parameter has `-` as a part of its string. Finally the line with `useradd` command will look like:

```
$ sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash -G interns -- "$i"
```

**Third**

Consider that usernames should satisfy the constraints. It depends on particular Linux distribution, here is quote from `man useradd` of Ubuntu 14.04

```
   It is usually recommended to only use usernames that begin with a lower
   case letter or an underscore, followed by lower case letters, digits,
   underscores, or dashes. They can end with a dollar sign. In regular
   expression terms: [a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]?

   On Debian, the only constraints are that usernames must neither start
   with a dash ('-') nor plus ('+') nor tilde ('~') nor contain a colon
   (':'), a comma (','), or a whitespace (space: ' ', end of line: '\n',
   tabulation: '\t', etc.). Note that using a slash ('/') may break the
   default algorithm for the definition of the user's home directory.

   Usernames may only be up to 32 characters long.
```

And finally read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) to be aware of other common mistakes.

Also take a look to `newusers` utility, it might be easier if you have tons of users to create.